# Playing sounds with javascript on mobile

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile

I have a webpage with basic Javascript cyclic timer script.
I want to play a sound every time the timer is restarted.

This is my script:

```
var audiof = new Audio('beep.mp3');

if (Seconds == 0) 
{ audiof.play(); }
```

Works fine on desktop. Doesn't work on mobile or tablet.

I've read that you cant play audio on mobile device unless triggered by the user. 
I wanted to add a button to start/stop the audio, can such event be a trigger to start audio ?
How can I solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: what mobile or table are you using? are you using and iPhone or another device. because on iPhone, you have to use a trick to get sound to play.

Comment: Yeah, the mobile I was testing with is an Iphone.

Comment: OK, later on today, I will post a work around on how you get sound to play on the iPhone. I just have to finish something up. but, yes, the iPhone has an issue with playing sound in HTML5 unless you actually have some kind of user interaction. like clicking on the screen.

Comment: I was thinking to add a sound on/off button. Starting with off, this will force the user to click it if he wants sound.

Comment: And thanks, waiting for your post !

Comment: that would do it, that would solve the problem.

Comment: you can alos add a splash screen, displaying the game/program title, with a click here to start button. when the person presses start, you can initialize the audiod at that point, an dit will play from that point an without any issues. so, yes, either way will work. I guess there is no need to post a code, what you said would work.

Comment: Start button could also work, but I am still not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using:

```
function clickbutton() {
    audiof.play();
    audiof.pause();
}
```

Any problems with this approach ?